# Restrict users to see websites and folders

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making an asp.net web site in C# and I have a database in slq server with a table `Users(id, username, password, isAdmin)`. The column `isAdmin` is `int` with default value `0`, so if the user is admin, `isAdmin = 1` else `isAdmin = 0`.

I have a login form in the website and when the user logs in, it creates a `Session("admin")` or `Session("user")`, depending on the `isAdmin` value.

So, how can I restrict access on `Session("user")` to `admin.aspx` page and to the upload folder on the site?

I don't want to add roles management in IIS, because the admin can make other users into admins (updating the `isAdmin` to `1`)

Thanks.

Comment: if the user is not admin then just redirect them to another page

Comment: Yes, that was my approach, but how yo deny access to the folder? He can write the URL to the folder and will be able to browse...

Comment: on page load of the restricted page. check my answer.

Comment: Turn off directory browsing. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off directory browsing in IIS.  Add this in your web.config to prevent users from browsing folders.  This is will work in IIS 7+

```
<configuration>
 <location path="Secured">
    <system.webServer>
      <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How does this prevent a non-admin user from going to "admin.aspx" page?

Comment: He asked two questions.  One about restricting admin page(which i answered in the comments) and two about restricting access to a folder.  See the comments in the original post.  He accepted this answer because that's what he really wanted answered.

Answer (score 3):

Don't keep standard user & admin in separate session variables. Rather create a class that maps to your User table and store user info in it in generic way. One property of that class would be `.isAdmin` (integer or even boolean). Then you could simple check something like in "admin.aspx"

```
UserInfo objUserInfo = (UserInfo)Session("user");

if (objUserInfo.isAdmin == 0) {
   Response.Redirect("User.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

something in this logic:

after logging in, save user role in session var first.
   and then in the page_load of the restricted page, check user's role and if he is not admin, redirect him to relogin with an admin account.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(session["role"].ToString().compareTo("admin")==0)
     {
     //load page stuff

     }
     else
     {
         Response.Redirect(your login page);
     }
}
```